# import from import in different folders in python

Tags: python

My directory structure is like,
[[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jk7II.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ppj7i.png)

python_file_without_extension contains

```
from py_file import function
```

In test_app.py, I want to write unit tests for python_file_without_extension and this is how I tried importing python_file_without_extension

```
import imp
import os

dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
file_path = dir_path.replace('test', 'app/python_file_without_extension')

file = imp.load_source('python_file_without_extension', file_path)

def test_func():
  #write test
   pass
```

I am getting error

```
from py_file import function
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'py_file'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try in your test file:

```py
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, "path to your main folder")
from app.py_file import py_func
```

Comment: E   ImportError: cannot import name 'py_func' from 'py_file' (unknown location)

Comment: E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app.py_file'

Comment: Please check the path to your main folder, i.e folder containing `app`